# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'reintroduceHouseStatus' of '(0 , _reactRedux.useSelector)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'reintroduceHouseStatus' of **'(0 , _reactRedux.useSelector)(...)' as it is undefined**.

[image]

As you see in the above screenshot, the only thing I've failed is passing `yarn test`.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { History } from 'history';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

import { House, User } from '../../api';
import { HouseCreateForm, HouseInviteModal, HouseManageModal } from '../../components';
import { houseStatus } from '../../constants/constants';
import { userActions } from '../../store/actions/index';
import { OrangeGlobalState } from '../../store/state';

interface Props {
  history: History;
  house: House;
  me: User;
}

function HousePage(props: Props) {
  const [houses, setHouses] = useState<[House]>();
  const [houseToBeInvited, setHouseToBeInvited] = useState<House>();
  const { getMeStatus, me } = useSelector((state: OrangeGlobalState) => state.user);
  const { reintroduceHouseStatus, renameHouseStatus } = useSelector((
    state: OrangeGlobalState,
  ) => state.house);
```

When I try the below codes

```js
console.log('reintroduceHouseStatus : ', reintroduceHouseStatus);
console.log('renameHouseStatus : ', renameHouseStatus);
```

console returns two status when I execute the functions relating to the status.

[image]

I don't know why `getMeStatus` has no problem but `reintrudoceHouseStatus` and `renameHouseStatus` have. (already checked `state: OrangeGlobalState` to which two status referred. Is there any problem with the version of reactRedux?
I'm curious if anyone had had the same problem as me.

Thanks.

---

The below codes are from `src/App.test.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './App';
import { getMockStore, history } from './tests/mocks';

const mockStore = getMockStore({
  user: {
    me: {},
  },
  necessity: {
    necessities: [],
  },
});

test('renders app with mock store', () => {
  const app = render(
    <Provider store={mockStore}>
      <App history={history} />
    </Provider>,
  );
  expect(app.container.firstChild).toHaveClass('App');
});
```

Comment: When you create mock store for your test you have to set state.house to something.

Comment: But when I get new status from state.necessity like the below,

   
<<<  const { createPlaceStatus } = useSelector((
    state: OrangeGlobalState,
  ) => state.necessity);

>>>

createPlaceStatus doesn't make any problem in yarn test

Comment: Then do that instead, problem solved. I know what you just typed makes sense to you since you're working on the project but it doesn't make any sense to me. I have no idea what state.necessity is nor is it mentioned anywhere in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be great if you could provide some test code, but having faced this issue myself I can give a guess.

In the test file, if you used the `render` method (or any similar method, `render` is from the [testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#render)), you might have created a wrapper for the component, using `Provider` and created the store using `createStore`. Here you need to pass the state's reducer, and the default state (in your case, setting `state.house` to something)

```
<Provider store={createStore(houseReducer, { house: defaultState })}>
    <HousePage />
</Provider>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me :)
I've appended test codes.

As you've expected, I used the `render` method.

Until now, I didn't care about the test code file...

Comment: According to one of your previous comments, you seem to face no problem in `state.necessity`. That's because you set `necessity` to some 'defaultState' in your mockStore. You must do the same for `house` too.

Comment: I was able to commit into the project with your help Thanks!

https://github.com/gongmyeong-study/orangenongjang/pull/157/commits/d551170d173d2930725b0ca0c1539b6beb733369